What is the process for installing custom .whl packages inside ClearML-Agent?
I'm trying to run my code, which imports a custom Python package. How can I run this code on the agent with the default queue on ClearML? Additionally, could you also guide me through the process of installing a custom .whl package, for example, a 'helloworld' library?

I running Clearml-agent from Docker Container. if I need some .whl package I  download it into the Docker container and pip install package/name.whl
Also, you need to check into Clearml web > project > experiments > install packages and add your package if this is not in the list
